# Max memory usage on watchOS 2?

Tags: swift, memory, watchkit, apple-watch

I didn't find anything regarding the memory usage availavable for an app in watchOS 2. I'm currently developing an app for watchOS and I'm using Core Data in the watch side.

When I load 166 of 189 objects to an array, the app crashes, the memory usage at that point is 34mb. As the watch has 512mb of memory I'm not entirely sure how much can you use with just one app.

I'm gonna improve my code's performance and ram usage but eitherway I still don't know what amount of memory can I use as it's not availavable on Apple Developer portal as far as I know.

Would appreciate information regarding this matter if you know.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried profiling your application with the Instruments tool? (Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Instruments > Leaks)

Comment: Hi @CeaneLamerez ! Thanks for answering. I didn't use the Instrument tools, but I watched the memory usage in the debug section, I'm gonna give it a try, though!. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory usage for WatchKit Application and WatchKit extension is not documented yet . For more detail visit this [technical Q&A forum](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1894/_index.html) .

Comment: Yes, it's a shame. I can't really believe that Apple didn't document everything but for a reason.